# Why is Optional parameter value auto filled with routedata in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC action like this in a controller named "ReportController" :

```
[HttpGet]    
public virtual ActionResult Index(int id, Dictionary<string,string> filtersVal = null)
{
        ...
}
```

When I try to call the page like this : http://domain.com/report/index?id=1    It hits the action correctly but populates the "filerVal" parameter with MVC routing information like bellow:

> [0] = {[controller, report]}
>   [1] = {[action, index]}

How can I avoid this , so that filterVal parameter stays null.

Note that : we have recently moved to MVC5 .. it was working fine in MVC3 
Also : if I call the same action like this : 
http://domain.com/report/index?id=2&filterVal[0].Key=136&filterVal[0].Value=1  It then has the correct value in "filterVal" parameter.

Can anybody suggest how do i avoid the first scenario ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could pass an invalid value. `../Index?id=1&filterVal=null` in which case `filterVal` will be an empty `Dictionary` (count=0)

Comment: Thanks Stephen.. but we already have similar URL many places in the app.. I would like to find the cause of this issue... and fix it so that it works like before..without the 'way-around'.

Comment: Clearly, you must have some kind of custom model binder, or routing rule that is causing this parameter to be bound with data.  Have you searched your project for all references to this?  We can't really help here because we can't see your code.

Comment: The reason is that you have a property which is `Dictionary` and the `DefaultModelBinder` uses a `RouteValueDictionary` (which is a `Dictionary`) based on the request so I think if you don't specifically include a value, it just adds the route values to your parameter (would need to study the source code more to be sure). I suspect the only way to overcome this would be to create a custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: We have the same problem in a JSON POST. Even if the `Dictionary` isn't optional.

Answer (score -1):

If your route table has entry like this:

`{controller}/{action}/{id}`

, where `{id}` is optional, then you should visit your page by using url:

> http://yourdomain.com/index/1?xxx=yyy&aaa=bbb

Where `xxx=yyy` and `aaa=bbb` becomes the value in `filtersVal`.